# Sampling in Matlab with discrete pareto distribution

Tags: matlab, static, discrete-mathematics, random

I want produce `10000` numbers with  discrete Pareto distribution in matlab.

I wrote this code in R, but I want to write it in Matlab.

R code for  discrete Pareto:

```
N<-5 ##for instance,you need N large enough
i0<-(1:N)
p<-1/(i0^1.98); p<-p/sum(p)
X<-sample(i0,N,replace=TRUE,prob=p)
X
```

alpha=1.98 and you see discrete pPareto distribution in this link that q=0,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%E2%80%93Mandelbrot_law

My question is: How can I write this code in Matlab?

I use `randsample` in matlab and translated this code in matlab.

For example:

```
N=5;
for i0=1:N
    p=1/(i0.^1.98);
    P=p/sum(p);`
    X=randsample(i0,N,true,P);
    X
end
```

But it has an error.

Can anyone make a suggestion?

Comment: Can you include the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

1. Your code has an error in it:
   P=p/sum(p);`
   should be 
   P=p/sum(p);

(This may be a formatting thing that just needs to be edited, but it is not clear what your error is: so start here)

1. You might need the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox to use randsample, which requires an additional license.
2. If these don't fix it, try typing
   help randsample
   at the MATLAB terminal and verify your settings.

This looks to be the piece you are interested in (from the help):

> Y = randsample(N,K,true,W) or randsample(POPULATION,K,true,W) returns a
>      weighted sample, using positive weights W, taken with replacement.  W is
>      often a vector of probabilities. This function does not support weighted
>      sampling without replacement.

3. I think you may have a misunderstanding in your code.  It looks like you think `P` should be a distribution, but that means `p` would be an array or vector.  However, from your code

`p=1/(i0.^1.98);`

is just going to evaluate to a scalar value (i.e. `p`, for i0=1, evaluates to 1^(-1.98), and thus P will just be equal to 1.

Perhaps you are looking for something more like this?

```
N=5;
i0=1:N;
p=1./(i0.^1.98);
P=p/sum(p);
X=randsample(i0,N,true,P)
```

(I left off the last `;` so you can display the result to your terminal)

Comment: thank you user2254698.
 I forgot use ". "in p=1./(i0.^1.98);
and this here I think I shouldn't use   "for " !!

Comment: @samira - Yes, in general you want to avoid "for" loops in MATLAB where you can.  Your code will still work with for loops, but typically not optimized for MATLAB's runtime.  Are you happy with the answer, I gave?  If so, can you accept it?

Comment: Typically loop that requires"for"should be applied in Matlab but I do not know why I entered "for" it's give me errore and I have to remove it

Comment: @samira - 'for' loops are allowed and certainly will work in MATLAB, but in general your code will run more efficiently (in MATLAB) if you are able to vectorize it.  Vectorization was one of the early hurdles I had to get past when starting with MATLAB, here's a link if you are curious to read more If you are new to MATLAB, you may want to checkout this link on vectorization http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

Comment: @samira - Great; best of luck with the rest of your discrete Pareto distribution and related work.  I hope the transition continues smoothly.

Comment: the **Vectorization** is very good...reading this led me to know reason for my work .thanks :)